# How to show line numbers in vim on the right side of the buffer?

Tags: linux, vim

I have `set nu` in my `.vimrc` which shows line numbers on the left side of current buffer. I would like to see line numbers on the right side. How to achieve this?

UPDATE: This should also work for `set relativenumber`

Comment: This would make no sense unless your text was right justified...

Answer (score 2):

There's no way, unless you switch the complete UI to right-left mode via `:set rightleft` or `$ vim -H`. Even common workarounds such as using the *signs column* (which a plugin used to implement `'relativenumber'` before that was built-in) won't do, as those appear on the left as well. The only, very clumsy hack would be a thin scratch buffer in a vertical split on the right, but updating that and maintaining the rightmost position will be a royal pain.

I don't know how hard it would be to modify the source code to do this, but I guess it isn't trivial, and Bram is unlikely to accept such a patch. So, better get over it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`VIM`'s `Hebrew Mode` will put the line numbers on the right, with `set nu`

To start `VIM` in `Hebrew Mode` use `vim -H`

Documentation [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/hebrew.html#hebrew)

Warning: It does reverse your text to rightleft as well

Comment: Ford's "UK mode" will put the steering wheel on the right. Warning: it does roll the entire car onto its back.