# VIM show actual and relative line numbers at the same time

Tags: vim

Per default I have the relative numbers and actual numbers active on my vim sessions.
However I find myself switching quite often to the actual line numbers as I like to copy elements from a certain line below my current e.g: `:34t.`

My first idea was to have the full numbers left and the relative numbers right, but if nothing has changed in this regards in the last 4 years this post already gives a negative answer on this.
[How to show line numbers in vim on the right side of the buffer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174907/how-to-show-line-numbers-in-vim-on-the-right-side-of-the-buffer)

So my question would be: is there any way to have just both the actual and the relative line numbers displayed in two columns?

```
4 26
3 27
2 28
1 29
0 30 I
1 31
2 32
3 33
4 34
```

Comment: The closest option seems to be `:set number relativenumber`: https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#number_relativenumber There might be a plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624418/2072269

Comment: Doesn't hybrid line number work for you ? `set number relativenumber`  should show both relative numbers of other lines and actual number of current line

Comment: The hybrid line numbers is what I am currently use. But on a quick glance on the screen I can not tell what actual line number a line is on without navigating to it.

Comment: @muru Plugin looks like the solution. I'll give that a shot

Comment: You don't really need the actual line number, though. You can do, say `:.+8t.` to copy the 8th line from the current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to muru's suggestion the [RltvNmber](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/rltvnmbr-vim) Plugin is achieving what I initially was looking for however using the suggested `:+8t.` syntax might be the leaner solution.